# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Webcam blinking

Tags: webcam

[image]

I am working with the face-recognition library but when my webcam opened I noticed that it was blinking for no reason I checked this on a Windows device it works well and in other apps like OBS, Zoom, meet, and Discord it also works well but in Ubuntu Cheese app it is blinking and when I open webcam using the cv2 library it blinking can anyone help me to get out of this.